# Double underscore prefix in Swift variables

Tags: swift, naming-conventions

In the Advanced Swift talk, the generated code for an for loop is described as:

```
var __g: Generator = mySequence.generate()
while let x = __g.next() {
    // iterations here
}
```

Does the underscore prefix have some specific meaning?

Answer (score 0):

No, the underscore- and double-underscore-prefixes have no specific meaning in Swift. They conventionally imply "private" or "internal" declarations, but you can define variables beginning with as many underscores as you like.